# How can I symbolize a layer by multiple attributes (category and amount) in ArcGIS Pro 2.5?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro, arcgis-portal

I have a layer of properties that are categorized by type (text field - farm, house, business, etc.) and cost (numeric field). I want to assign each property type a different-shaped symbol (all of the same size) and to classify it to one of five cost categories by colour.

There are 120 properties, 5 cost classes to which they will be assigned, and 5 property types.

For example, all houses will be squares. Houses in cost class 1 will be green; cost class 2 will be blue; class 3 will be red; etc.

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.5 and will be publishing the layer to Portal for ArcGIS.

Comment: What have you tried?  What was the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select Unique Values Symbology, under the drop down you would choose to select a field is a big button that says ADD FIELD, so your first field would be building type, second you be cost then you'll have the combinations you need to symbolize.

Comment: I'd have to manually assign them to the correct cost category then. Is there a way to do that automatically with the symbology (a la graduated colours, but separate colours)? Or, to get around that I could add a field that has the cost category attribute and then use your method. But there are several combinations and assigning each one a symbol manually is a bit of time and error-prone. What would be a workaround if I had many, many different categories and combinations and didn't want to manually assign the symbol to each combination?

Comment: If you want to automate symbology you need to get into python and the CIM module.